# call socket when return data after save in database in ndoejs and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

i want to send notification to user after save that notification into database .

**first :** i want save data in databse :

**second :** i want to return the user `FirstName adn lastName`

```
   async CreateNotification(item): Promise<any> {
    const requestModel = new NotificationModel();
    requestModel.sender = item.sender;
    requestModel.reciver = item.reciver;
    requestModel.notificationType = item.notificationType;
    requestModel.sendDate = new Date();
  return  requestModel.save()
        .then((data) => {
            this.GetNOtificationById(data)
            .then(data=>{
              return data;
            })
        });
}

async GetNOtificationById(data) {
    let item = await NotificationModel
        .findOne({ sender: data.sender, reciver: data.reciver, notificationType: data.notificationType })
        .populate({ path: 'sender', select: "firstName lastName" }).exec();
    return item;
}
```

**three :** i want to return that data and use that in socket :

```
    socket.on('send Notificaiton', (data) => {
    let item;
    notificationRepository.CreateNotification(data)
        .then(data => {
            item = data;
        })
    io.sockets.in(data.reciver).emit('notification', { id: item.id, senderId: item.sender._id, notificationType: item.notificationType, senderName: item.sender.firstName + ' ' + item.sender.lastName });
})
```

but i have a problem with this code , some time its works fine and some times it return item=`null` in step **three** .

**now how can i solve this problem ???**

Comment: you may want `then((data) => { return this.GetNOtificationById(data)` - and there's never any need to `.then(data=>{ return data; })` - that's basically a NOOP - it doesn't make asynchronous results available synchronously

Comment: @JaromandaX i try your code but its not worked

Comment: you have more issues than that ... the answer below should make it work

Comment: @JaromandaX its not worked for me man

Comment: as I said, many issues in your code - work with the person who is trying to help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're not waiting for the `notification creation`.

```
// Notication
async CreateNotification(item): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const requestModel = new NotificationModel();
      requestModel.sender = item.sender;
      requestModel.reciver = item.reciver;
      requestModel.notificationType = item.notificationType;
      requestModel.sendDate = new Date();
      const data = await requestModel.save()
      const result = await this.GetNOtificationById(data)
      return result 
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
      throw err
    }
}
```

```
socket.on('send Notificaiton', async (data) => {
  try {
    const item = await notificationRepository.CreateNotification(data)
    if (item) {
      io.sockets.in(data.reciver).emit('notification', { id: item.id, senderId: 
      item.sender._id, notificationType: item.notificationType, senderName: 
      item.sender.firstName + ' ' + item.sender.lastName });
    } else {
      console.log('Item does not exist', item)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error while creating item: ', err)
  }
```

Comment: Can you check now!

Comment: you need to find out why item not created,

Comment: in first time it show me that `null` message and in the other try it find worked.

Comment: Why are you calling `GetNOtificationById ` after `save`, why can't you return the item which is `created`?

Comment: Would have to guess that `requestModel.save()` doesn't return an appropriate promise.

Comment: @Naren i want to retrun userInfo with populated . for this i return create a function for return user info with userId .